# Warning in R: "wrong result size (7), expected 239177 or 1"

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I want to run the following R code in shiny

**server.R**

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
library(mgcv)

data <- read.csv("..\\GlobalLandTemperatures\\GlobalLandTemperaturesByMajorCity.csv", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$overview<-renderText("This Shiny App provides a fast and easy way to explore the \"Earth Surface Temperature Data\" published on Kaggle and compiled originally by \"Berkeley Earth\". 
                              Here you can plot the average temprature over time from 1900-2014 in 100 major cities.
                              The model used is a Generalized Additive Model(GAM)")


  #read the 100 cities names (the unique values)
  CityNames<-unique(data$City) 

  #Cities names list
  output$CitySelector<-renderUI({
    selectInput('cities', 'City',
                CityNames, 
                multiple=TRUE, 
                selectize=TRUE, 
                selected="Jakarta") #default value
  })

  #Months abbreviation list
  output$MonthSelector<-renderUI({
    selectInput('months', 'Month', 
                set_names(c(1:12),month.abb), 
                multiple=TRUE, 
                selectize=TRUE,
                selected=1) #default January
  })

  #get the selected cities
  SelectedCity<-reactive({

    if(is.null(input$cities) || length(input$cities)==0)
      return()
    as.vector(input$cities)

  })

  #get the selected month
  SelectedMonth<-reactive({

    if(is.null(input$months) || length(input$months)==0)
      return()
    as.numeric(as.vector(input$months))

  })


  #filter the data according to the selected city and month/s
  citiesDF<-reactive({
    data %>%
      unnest(data)%>%
      filter(City %in% SelectedCity()) %>%
      filter(Month %in% SelectedMonth())
  }) 

  output$ff <- renderPrint({
    names(citiesDF())
  })

  #get Check group input (type of plot)
  checkedVal <- reactive({
    as.vector(input$checkPlot)

  }) 

  ############PLOT#########
  output$RegPlot<-renderPlot({
    #check if city and month are not null
    if ((length(SelectedCity())>0) && (length(SelectedMonth())>0))

    {g<-ggplot(citiesDF(),
               aes(x=dt,y=AverageTemperature,
                   colour=factor(Month)))+
      labs(x="Year",
           y="Average Temperature")+
      facet_wrap(~City)+
      scale_color_discrete(name="Month",
                           breaks=c(1:12),
                           labels=month.abb)

    if ("GAM Plot" %in% checkedVal())

      g<-g+stat_smooth(method="gam", formula=y~s(x),se=FALSE)

    if ("Point Plot" %in% checkedVal())

      g<-g+geom_point(aes(alpha=0.4))+
        guides(alpha=FALSE)

    g
    }
  })
  #########################
})
```

but I get the error "**wrong result size (7), expected 239177 or 1**". I researched it and I try to remove library dplyr or move it to top but it didn't work out.

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


# Define UI for miles per gallon application
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Climate Change in Major Cities (1900-2014)"),

  # Sidebar with controls to select city, month and type of plot
  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Type/Select one or more cities:"),

      uiOutput("CitySelector"),

      helpText("Type/Select one or more months:"),
      uiOutput("MonthSelector"),

      helpText("Select type of plot:"),
      checkboxGroupInput("checkPlot", 
                         label = ("Plots"), 
                         choices=c("GAM Plot","Point Plot"),
                         selected = "GAM Plot"
      ),

      helpText("Note that : \"Early data was collected by technicians using mercury thermometers, where any variation in the visit time impacted measurements. In the 1940s, the construction of airports caused many weather stations to be moved. In the 1980s, there was a move to electronic thermometers that are said to have a cooling bias.\""),

      tags$a(href = "https://www.kaggle.com/berkeleyearth/climate-change-earth-surface-temperature-data", "Source")

    ),

    #Main Panel contains the plot/s
    mainPanel(

      textOutput("overview"),
      plotOutput("RegPlot")
      # verbatimTextOutput("ff")


    )
  )
))
```

What other options are there to overcome this?

data at [GlobalLandTemperaturesByMajorCity](https://ufile.io/0cd38)

Comment: Please include a sample dataset to reproduce

Comment: see updated please @HubertL

Comment: OK Could you also provide ui?

Comment: @HubertL I just updated

Comment: Your problem comes from calling `unnest` which is not the appropriate way to extract Month from Date.

Comment: So instead of `unnest` what do you recommend me to use ? @HubertL

Comment: Look at `?months()` but this won't be compatible with `month.abb`

Comment: Is it possible to get rid of it and substitute it with something else ? @HubertL